# Dealing with floating point point inaccuracy in very small numbers efficiently

Tags: java, math, floating-point, double, precision

The program I am working with takes OpenStreetMap data to render a map. The data consists of 4 coordinates, that make up the bounds of the data.

I am drawing lines, that sometimes exceed these bounds - I want to make the lines stop at the exact point of the bounds, when a line consisting of a point inside & and outside the bounds occur. Since I have knowledge of the points of the bounds, and the point inside and outside the bounds - I can calculate the intersection between these two lines, but the inaccuracy is very inconsistent. In the 
[first picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9uIp.png), you can see, where the intersection is on the line. On the [second picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRpEj.png), you can see where the intersection is supposed to be between - this is the worst case I have experienced.

These are the coordinates I am working with:

- Point one: x: 7.040283679962158, y: -55.59856033325195
- Point two: x: 7.04131555557251, y: -55.5977783203125
- Point three: x: 6.991822718617924, y: -55.5984
- Point four: x: 7.2029868530932735, y: -55.5984
- Intersection point: x: 7.039072513580322, y: -55.5984001159668
- Wolfram alpha suggests that x should be approx. 7.0405.

As the numbers are very small and the calculations are many, I suppose that there is a lot of loss inbetween the calculations, this is the code, that does the calculations - sorry for forcing you to read this discount-ghetto-code. OSMNode contain longitude and latitude coordinates - so they act as Point2D in this sense.

```
private OSMNode calculateIntersectionNode(OSMNode line1Node1, OSMNode line1Node2, OSMNode line2Node1, OSMNode line2Node2) {
    double lon1 = line1Node1.getLon();
    double lon2 = line1Node2.getLon();
    double lon3 = line2Node1.getLon();
    double lon4 = line2Node2.getLon();
    double lat1 = line1Node1.getLat();
    double lat2 = line1Node2.getLat();
    double lat3 = line2Node1.getLat();
    double lat4 = line2Node2.getLat();
    double intersectionLon = ( ( (((lon1*lat2) - (lat1*lon2)) * (lon3-lon4)) - ((lon1-lon2) * ((lon3*lat4) - (lat3*lon4))) ) / ( ((lon1 - lon2) * (lat3 - lat4)) - ( (lat1 - lat2) * (lon3 - lon4)) ) );
    double intersectionLat = ( ( (((lon1*lat2) - (lat1*lon2)) * (lat3-lat4)) - ((lat1-lat2) * ((lon3*lat4) - (lat3*lon4))) ) / ( ((lon1 - lon2) * (lat3 - lat4)) - ( (lat1 - lat2) * (lon3 - lon4)) ) );
    return new OSMNode(intersectionLon, intersectionLat);
}
```

Do I throw more precision at the code somehow? Do I change the way that I calculate the intersection or something third - I am currently empty inside my head.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't tested, but a first step would be to try to distribute all the multiplications over subtractions to force any mults before the subtracts.  A possible source of instability is subtracting to get something imprecise near machine precision that's correlated with a very large multiplication that magnifies the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick attention, but despite rigorous testing - the fault was again over at my shoddy coding.

I will keep the arithmetic tip in mind for the future, thanks again!

Comment: @GregoryBush: How could distributing the multiplications help? The subtractions still occur, and multiplying does not change the relative magnitudes of the errors. Subtraction is only unstable in the sense that the error in the result of subtracting two values of similar magnitude is larger **relative** to the result than it is relative to the operands. But that is only because the result is smaller than the operands. A subtraction of two values of similar magnitude introduces no new error. Multiplying before or after changes little.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this: 
public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  double e = Math.ulp(0.0);
  double n5 = 5.0 * e;
  double n6 = 6.0 * e;
  System.out.println(1e308 * (n6 * 0.1 - n5 * 0.1) * 1e117);
  System.out.println(1e308 * n6 * 0.1 * 1e117 - 1e308 * n5 * 0.1 * 1e117);
 }
 
}

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, the fault was my own - the issue was an index error, which was extremely hard to spot, due to  working with a function returning exclusive index-values, while I was working with inclusive in the rest of the class.

I don't know what tradition is around here - do I close the question or delete it?

Comment: you should be able to delete it still. otherwise it can be closed as Off-Topic